# Iterate and update table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `person_relation`

```
Id  | ParentId    |  ChildId  | PersonId    
-------------------------------------------
1   |    null     |  2        |   null     
-------------------------------------------
2   |     1       |  3        |   null      
-------------------------------------------
3   |     2       |  4        |    122
-------------------------------------------
4   |     3       |  null     |    122
-------------------------------------------
```

These 4 rows belong to one single person whose id is 122. 
I am struggling in updating the PersonId column; the first 2 rows should have 122 as PersonId.

---

```
Id  | ParentId    |  ChildId  | PersonId    
-------------------------------------------
1   |    null     |  2        |   null     
-------------------------------------------
2   |     1       |  3        |   null      
-------------------------------------------
3   |     2       |  4        |    122
-------------------------------------------
4   |     3       |  null     |    122
-------------------------------------------
5   |    null     |  6        |   123
-------------------------------------------
6   |     5       |  7        |   null      
-------------------------------------------
7   |     6       |  8        |    123
-------------------------------------------
8   |     7       |  null     |    null   
-------------------------------------------
```

Now the table has two persons whose ids are 122 and 123. And it may have many persons in it.
So the above replies wont work. Hence we need an iterative method to update these rows.

Comment: "should have"? then why is it not having?

Answer (score 1):

```
update person_relation 
set personid = 122
where personid is null
```

Comment: It works on the sample data.  I suspect it may not cover all the scenarios that exist in the real data.  It smacks of wanting a bottom-up hierarchical search, ensuring that all the rows starting from a row with NULL for the ChildID (and probably non-null for the PersonID) all have the same PersonID.  Or maybe you aren't supposed to make assumptions about the the leaf-node being correct; maybe it is another node that should be deemed correct.  Or maybe you need to do majority voting on what's correct.  Or ... in general, the full scope of the problem is under-specified.

Answer (score 0):

Juergen's answer will get the job done, but I'd be willing to bet that your dataset is not limited to those four rows. I would do something a little safer:

```
update person_relation
set PersonId = 122
where Id IN (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There Should be a relation in parent_id.. If 4 of them are belongs to family. Then their children should hav the parentID column value as thier parents ID number...(either 1 or 2 in  this case). and i wonder how the parent Id can be **null** if they are of same family..?

If the parents Id is proper, Then u can update the personID of childrens properly.

Comment: Please dont consider this table as something rigid. I mentioned it for the sake of example. In the above table row1 and row5 are root. I am more concerned about how to update the personid.

Comment: atleast one child will hav personId value populated for sure?